# Flurry SDK: How to add event description and how to use event parameters?

Tags: ios, events, sdk, flurry

I have tested `flurry` for iOS.
I've found, that i don't know how to add event description programmically.
Also, i don't understand, for which reason i should use event parameters. (only for segmentation?)
Maybe it is possible to add into parameters dictionary "event description"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];
```

You can use logEvent to count the number of times certain events happen during a session of your application. This can be useful for measuring how often users perform various actions.

Parameters give context to your events by collecting metadata when an event is triggered.

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME" withParameters:YOUR_NSDictionary];
```

You can use this version of logEvent to count the number of times certain events happen during a session of your application and to pass dynamic parameters to be recorded with that event. Event parameters can be passed in as a NSDictionary object where the key and value objects must be NSString objects. For example, you could record that a user used your search box tool and also dynamically record which search terms the user entered.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: thanks, but how `event parameters` appears on site? and is it possible to add event description? (i log some events and see, that i must add description of event on site. is it possible to do in `app`)?